# Filtering a many to many (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

```
create table "users"(
  "id"        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "full_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  "role"      integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "email"     varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

create table "devices"(
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "brand_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

create table "users_and_devices"(
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "device_id" integer NOT NULL,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id),
    foreign key (device_id) references devices(id)
);
```

How can I get the `brand_name` of all devices that belong to `user 1` ? And should I add indexes to `user_id` and `device_id` in `users_and_devices` ?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably should have a `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, device_id)` on table `users_and_devices`. This would not only prevent pointless duplicates but also serve as index to speed up the query you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is a simple join across the devices and users_and_devices tables.  Did you try that?

```
select brand_name 
from devices d
left join users_and_devices ud on (ud.device_id=d.id)
where ud.user_id=1
```

And yes, I'd put an index on user_id and device_id because you're going to be querying the table for those specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

All brands owned by user_id 1, eliminating duplicates:

```
select distinct d.brand_name
from users_and_devices ud
inner join devices d on ud.device_id = d.id
where ud.user_id = 1
```